# T-SQL subquery does not accept Alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SSMS 2019 and Report builder to make reports, MY problem is in this query it does not accept AS

```
SELECT Country,ServiceGrade as BestCenter from VW_FactCallCenter
         WHERE EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT Country, MAX(ServiceGrade) as MaxGrade FROM VW_FactCallCenter GROUP BY Country) AS BestCenter
```

With this Query I get my desired Result, But when I add subquery to it, I cant use 2 column, when I use `With Exists` then I cant use Alias

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country, MAX(ServiceGrade) as MaxGrade FROM VW_FactCallCenter GROUP BY Country
```

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ergup.png)

This is my DDL

```
CREATE view VW_FactCallCenter (IssuesRaised Smallint, 
                            LevelOneOperators Smallint,
                            LevelTwoOperators Smallint, 
                            ServiceGrade Float, 
                            Shift Nvarchar(20),
                            Date Datetime,
                            TotalOperators Smallint,
                            Country Varchar(7) )


INSERT into VW_FactCallCenter (IssuesRaised, 
                                LevelOneOperators ,
                                LevelTwoOperators , 
                                ServiceGrade , 
                                Shift,
                                Date ,
                                TotalOperators,
                                Country ) VALUES (1,1,4,0.12,'midnight','2014-05-05',5,'Italy');
                                

INSERT into VW_FactCallCenter (IssuesRaised, 
                                LevelOneOperators ,
                                LevelTwoOperators , 
                                ServiceGrade , 
                                Shift,
                                Date ,
                                TotalOperators,
                                Country ) VALUES (2,2,7,0.18,'AM','2014-08-12',9,'France');

INSERT into VW_FactCallCenter (IssuesRaised, 
                                LevelOneOperators ,
                                LevelTwoOperators , 
                                ServiceGrade , 
                                Shift,
                                Date ,
                                TotalOperators,
                                Country ) VALUES (4,5,7,0.21,'AM','2014-09-12',12,'Germany');
```

My goal is to compare Call Centers depending on Country as you can see in the Desired Result image, I am thinking to use Concat but without using that is there a way to do it? Unfortunately I have been asking this problem to my supervisor but he seems so busy so I need help, I have been trying to solve this problem since yesterday I have tried other methods but I really want to use Alias for a report in my subquery

Comment: The terms inside a `WHERE` clause are used to filter the result set, there would be no point in assigning aliases to them.

Comment: The exists subquery does not take an alias, and also your intended logic is not clear.

Comment: You do not use an alias with *exists*, you don't make any correlation with your *exists*, it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as I see I should use concat, if I dont use Where Exists then in subquery it only accept 1 column, I tried where exists to see 2 column but I will merge that 2 column to be more clear, I have described my intended logic, its simple, to compare callcenters that between countries, I am new to this, I have too much to learn, could you please describe me what you dont get ?

Comment: @Stu ok thank you for informing me, I will try to use concat, to merge 2 column as 1 is this a correct approach? I am trying to compare countries that has call centers inside of it, maxgrade is for grading them, there are various centers inside of countries but I just want to see the most sucessful (grades that is higher than 0.10 is good) in the image Italy has the best center, if it makes clear I am using AdventureWorksDW2019 as sample DB

Comment: I have no idea what it is you are trying to do, you have not explained your data or how you get to your desired results. For a start your image has 3 rows, your data is only two.

Comment: @Stu I have upload it, could you check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Side point: `DISTINCT` is completely bogus here because you have a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can find greatest service grade per country like so:

```
SELECT Country, ServiceGrade
FROM VW_FactCallCenter AS t1
WHERE ServiceGrade = (
    SELECT MAX(ServiceGrade)
    FROM VW_FactCallCenter AS t2
    WHERE t2.Country = t1.Country
)
```